# Detect what is in brackets in two lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

if I have a text like this

```
1
<src> he is a [man]</src>
<tgt>lui è un [uomo]</tgt>
2
<src> she is a [woman]</src>
<tgt>lei è una donna</tgt>
3
<src> he works well</src>
<tgt> lui lavora [bene]</tgt>
```

and I want to detect the strings between the brackets only if the brackets are present in the src and tgt line, so in the text above, I want to detect only [man][uomo], because in the src line there is [man] and in the tgt line there is [uomo]. Can someone help me

I tried this code

```
line = str()
num = str()
line1 = str()
num1 = str()

for i, line in enumerate(file):
    lines = iter(filer1)
    if line.startswith("<src>"):
        line += '%s\n' % line.strip()
        num += '%s\n' % filer1[i-1]
    if line.startswith("<tgt>"):
        line1 += '%s\n' % line.strip()
        num1 += '%s\n' % filer1[i-2]
for l in line.splitlines():
      for ll in line1.splitlines():
          for n in num.splitlines():
              for nn in num1.splitlines():
                   if n ==nn:
                      m = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",l)
                      mm = re.findall(r"\[(.*?)\]",ll)
                      if m and mm:
                            print '[{}]'.format(m[0]), '[{}]'.format(mm[0])
```

Comment: Do you want all strings in square brackets anywhere or only strings within your angle-bracketed tags that are within square brackets? Also, you're supposed to come here once you're stuck, not before you start (you have no code; you're just asking us to do it for you).

Comment: Look into using python's regex module (`import re`).

Comment: Downvote removed since you posted your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, what you should do is: first, clean up your text input so that you have a list of lists, where each sublist contains a src line and a tgt line. Then, loop over the pairs of lines, and use `re` to test for the presence of text within square brackets in both src and tgt. If both src and tgt have bracketed text, display them; otherwise, don't.

This should be pretty straightforward, and should look something like the below:

```
import re

# see <http://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/1535629>
def chunks(l, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i+n]

text = '''1
<src> he is a [man]</src>
<tgt>lui è un [uomo]</tgt>
2
<src> she is a [woman]</src>
<tgt>lei è una donna</tgt>
3
<src> he works well</src>
<tgt> lui lavora [bene]</tgt>'''
lines = text.split('\n')
linepairs = [chunk[1:] for chunk in chunks(lines, 3)]

regex = re.compile(r'\[\w*\]')
for src, tgt in linepairs:
    src_match = re.search(regex, src)
    tgt_match = re.search(regex, tgt)
    if src_match and tgt_match:
        print(src_match.group(), tgt_match.group())
```

Result:

```
[man] [uomo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file strictly follows the three-line pattern, you could do

```
# assumes Python 2.7
from itertools import izip_longest
import re

INPUT = "translations.txt"

# from itertools documentation
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

in_brackets = re.compile("\[(.*?)\]").search

def main():
    with open(INPUT) as inf:
        for num,en,it in grouper(inf, 3, ""):
            en = in_brackets(en)
            it = in_brackets(it)
            if en and it:
                print("[{}] -> [{}]".format(en.group(1), it.group(1)))

main()
```